# How to lift results from search engine in my website using cURL

Tags: php, search, user-interface, curl, web

I am trying to develop a site which should act as a personalized search tool (i:e)search results based on user interests and the keyword entered by the user.
Currently i want to use cURL to display results,
My doubt is ,

whenever the user search a keyword in my website search tab ,the results should be lifted from search engines and the results should be published in my site.

How can i use cURL to display search results based on the keyword pinged by the user in the search area .

Help me friends .
thanks in advance

Comment: [`What have you tried?`](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check

[Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/)

[Php Curl Docs](http://sg3.php.net/curl)

there are a lot of examples and use cases in both websites regarding to your question.